Variations on interlaced fingers
Based on Kabbalah some have the custom to not join hands together with interlaced fingers.
Classically, that looks something like this:

But what about if the fingers are on the inside, like this:

According to those that uphold this custom, is that equally problematic?
Also, what about two people holding hands with interlaced fingers?

Is interlacing them but not combining them together into a ball (not in prayer form) also asur?

Based on the sources in the link you gave, interlocking in any way would be problematic. However, with another person where both are the right or both left, shouldn’t be an issue

@Chatzkel Not sure why you're assuming they're the same hand.

@shmosel I’m not assuming that. I’m saying IF that’s the case it shouldn’t be a problem. If it’s right and left then it should be. The issue is mixing the right and left
